# Add resource path to UIWebView Cordova IOS

Tags: ios, url, cordova, uiwebview

I am using Phonegap for developing an IOS application and I want to add a resource path, which is located in the Directories folder of my application, in the main UIWebView.

I know I have to set the baseURL to this exact path but I can't seem to find the way to obtain the UIWebView Object somehow.

I have also noticed that in the native part:

```
self.viewController = [[[MainViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
self.viewController.useSplashScreen = YES;
self.viewController.wwwFolderName = @"www";
self.viewController.startPage = @"index.html";
self.viewController.invokeString = invokeString;
self.viewController.view.frame = viewBounds;
```

This snippet is located in the *didFinishLaunchingWithOptions* in the *AppDelegate.m* so I guess I should add a property of the resource path(?), but I can't find out how I should do this.

Any help or an alternative perspective would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

yes I have noticed that method, but it is not working the way I want it to work. So let me explain what the case is: I have the .html files that I want to display in my project folder. The goal is to download css files in initialization phase of the app and then load the main web view with the reference in the folder of my previously downloaded css. I know it can be done with the "file:" protocol in the link of the css reference but unfortunately we don't know the exact path in order to include it in the html files. If I change the resource path to my downloaded folder then the application can't find the index.html.

So my question is that if anyone can in someway load the html files and make a "reference" in a downloaded css folder. An example code would be:

```
in index.html:
<link href="/allCss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The allCss file is located in a local folder in my application which is downloaded as I already stated.

My first guess was to "add" a resource path, but it doesn't work as expected. Any other suggestions of how to approach this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

in the mainviewcontroller.m

this method will helpful. just uncomment and try

```
- (NSString*) pathForResource:(NSString*)resourcepath;
{
return [super pathForResource:resourcepath];
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question, this is not working how I am expecting to work.